# MS SQL Index column sort order matters?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a database where I run profiler and database advisor to improve the performance of the database. I did and so far so good, the advisor presented me lots of indexes and statistics that can be created to get better performance.
But reading the statements I ran into this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_xinfobaseacl_11_397426127__K3_K7_K1_K5] ON [dbo].[xinfobaseacl] 
(
    [lviewid] ASC,
    [lparentid] ASC,
    [lid] ASC,
    [xlactor] ASC
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
go

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [_dta_index_xinfobaseacl_11_397426127__K7_K5_K1_K3] ON [dbo].[xinfobaseacl] 
(
    [lparentid] ASC,
    [xlactor] ASC,
    [lid] ASC,
    [lviewid] ASC
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
go
```

Same table, same columns, same parameters, just other sort order of the columns...

**So I am confused, does the sort order really matters in index creation???**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the order of the columns in a composite index matters.

Both of them will work equally well for an equality predicate on all 4 columns.

But the first one will additionally support queries like

```
WHERE lviewid =  1 AND lparentid 1 AND lid = 1
ORDER BY xlactor
```

And the second one will support queries such as

```
WHERE parentid =  1 AND xlactor = 1
ORDER BY lid, xlactor
```

Whether or not you should create both indexes depends on your workload. Did you feed the DTA a representative workload including data modification statements?

Comment: That means in fact that we have to seek all our source code if the usage in the WHERE statement are in the correct sort order of the index to prevent many indexes of the same content, am I right? As this was created by the advisor we probably have queries on the same content with different sort order in the WHERE statement.

Comment: And: If the index for a wrong sort order usage did not exists he won't use the other existing index, correct?

Comment: @YvesR - If your first comment is asking whether the order of the predicates in the `WHERE` needs to be the same as in the index definition then the answer is "no". Because `lviewid` is the initial column in the first index and the last column in the second index there is no subset of three columns that both indexes can seek into. So apart from the case of an equality predicate on all 4 columns they generally will help support different queries.

Comment: then I am wondering why the advisor offer two indexes, because our source code do not use ORDER BY queries for this table for sure, just something like ´EXISTS(SELECT * FROM xinfobaseacl WHERE ...´

Comment: `ORDER BY` is just one example. It has suggested it as a key column rather than an included column so I guess the DTA isn't just including it for covering purposes. The first index would also support `MAX(xlactor) ... WHERE lviewid =  1 AND lparentid 1 AND lid = 1` for example. Or maybe it is just a redundant suggestion from the DTA. Without knowing your queries impossible for me to tell.

Comment: Ok, most important to me is that the WHERE statements use the index if the columns are used in different sort order, all other stuff seems to be fine tuning.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing terminologies.  The sort order doesn't have a great, if any, affect, but the order of the columns in the index can be important.

The correct order of columns for a compound index depends on your query, but as a rule of thumb, the column with the fewest different values should be first.

Comment: Though the order of the columns in a composite index do affect the overall sort order of the index. Maybe that's what they mean.

Comment: @MartinSmith Perhaps. In the example given though, the sort order is the same for all columns.

Comment: Well the first one is sorted by `[lviewid] ASC,[lparentid] ASC, [lid] ASC, [xlactor] ASC` and the second one by `[lparentid] ASC,
    [xlactor] ASC,
    [lid] ASC,
    [lviewid] ASC`

Comment: For this example we did not have any ORDER BY, just WHERE statements to check of existance of the records as this table represents a access control list functionality. So the advisor found usages of two different WHERE statements on the same columns, just other sort order, it seems...